# AS3 - replacing / taking over base AS function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have following scenario:
I load many external swf files (they are at same domain) dynamically inside my AS3 loader.
All of them using navigateToURL (AS3) or getURL (AS2) on some buttons, that redirects to currently no more existing old domain.
Is it possible to replace (take over) navigateToURL and getURL base AS functions to change redirect link to up to date one or at least block loaded swf from opening urls?

Comment: you want to "catch the function calls" (kind of..) !?
maybe you should edit the swf in swf editor like sothink and correct the url's ?!

Comment: There are a lot of them. So, is it possible to catch base AS function for this or block url redirections?

Comment: You'd better place a 302 redirect on the old domain, or rewrite the URLs in SWF source.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can [extend](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#extends) classes, and implement your own [override](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#override) for methods/properties, but the previously compiled swf would need to point to your new class (which it won't).

You could try catching the error thrown (perhaps with [UncaughtErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html)) and judiciously interpret the intended URL and dispatch the appropriate commands.  The ideal would still be to just recompile the loaded SWF after running a search-and-replace for the deprecated method.